# Altering headers along big table

Tags: python, r

Having a tab-delimited table as the one below, how would one alter the 'ARS' headers so as to correspond to the previous order?

```
label   Group   numOtus Otu000001   OtuARS1 OtuARS2 OtuARS3
0.03    ARS     3448    1           4100    0       0
0.03    ARS     3448    0           3541    0       0
```

This is, how would a script 'rename' OtuARS1 to Otu000002, and so on, following the rest of the tab-delimited table (500+ headers)?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
André

Comment: What have you tried so far, in terms of code? Do you know R or Python? Do you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

Using `R` and assuming the name of your data is `yourdata`...

Find indices of variables with 'OtuARS'

```
old.names <- grep("OtuARS",names(yourdata))
```

Create new names

```
new.names <- paste0("Otu00000",2:(length(old.names)+1))
```

Actually change names in table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(yourdata)
setnames(yourdata,old.names,new.names)
```